# Find the number of second-degree polynomials $f(x)$ with integer coefficients and integer zeros for which $f(0)=2010.$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> Find the number of second-degree polynomials $f(x)$ with integer coefficients and integer zeros for which $f(0)=2010.$

I know that if the coefficients and roots are integers then for every $r \in \Bbb Z$ with $f(r) = 0$ we have that $r \mid 2010$ since for $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ we have that $f(0)=c = 2010$.

So every root $r$ of $f$ divides $2010$. Now $2010=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot67$ so it has $16$ divisors.

What kind of consdierations I should do know? Since $\deg f=2$ from the $16$ possible choices for the roots only $2$ are applicable.

I don't quite know how I can turn this data to figure out the possible coefficients for $f.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ the interger roots. You know that

$$x_1x_2=\frac{2010}{a}$$
$$x_1+x_2=-\frac ba$$

It means that $a$ divide $b$ and $2010$.

Can you finish?

Comment: I don't quite know what can I do with the second condition $x_1+x_2=-\frac ba$?

Comment: @JiinaJojlo, Since you test possible roots in the first equation, you find possible values for $a$. Considering these values for $a$, you can find suitable values for $b$, using the second condition.